# Seting two positions for one element in css

Tags: css, web, position

I have a `div` element floating absolutly on mouse position. so I set its `position` to `absolute`:

```css
div#floating{  
    position:absolute;  
}
```

I want to have a `[close]` link (with absolute position in my div) to hide my floating div. so I have to:

```css
a#close{  
  position: absolute;  
}
```

and

```css
div#floating{
   position:relative;  
}
```

how can I set two positions (absolute and relative) for my floating div?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? The reason I ask is because there's probably a better way to do this. Are you trying to do a "modal" window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set both to absolute.because an absolutely positioned element that is inside another absolutely or relatively positioned element is computed relative to its parent.

```
 div#floating{ 
    position:absolute;  
 }  

 a#close{  
   position: absolute;  
 }
```

check this : http://jsfiddle.net/6ddDw/

Answer (score 0):

i think you can not do that.

try to put a div inside the floating div and make it position relative.

Answer (score 0):

No, can't do that, because if you set two positions to one element only the last one would apply to it.